# how to set textview inside dialog box on item click

Tags: android, dialog, textview, sqlite

Here is my code, that I am trying to do since last two days. All I can see is the listView in mainActivity and when the listitem is clicked a alertdialog box appears without any datas from database in textView. I think Cursor cursor is not working, that is why I cannot reach to my goal. Could anyone suggest me some good solution for this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //creating a main list view
    final ArrayList<String> getTrainingsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getTrainingsList);

    ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.traininglistView);
    mylist.setAdapter(adapter);

    String Path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    //opening an existing database
    final SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Path, null, 0);

    final String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM training";

    //Getting a cursor to fetch data from the database
    final Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    Log.d("TAG","cursor found");
    c.moveToFirst();
    Log.d("TAG","Cursor moved to first");
    if(c !=null){
        //If there are contents in the database,
        //then c!=null, so using do-while loop access data in database
        do{
            String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title"));
            //String description = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("description"));
            //String title_date = title+":"+date;
            getTrainingsList.add(title);
            c.moveToNext();
        }while(!c.isAfterLast());


        //update the list
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        //closing the database after use
        //db.close();
    }   

    //Below is the code to alert alert dialogue window on item clicked
    final TextView view1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dialogTextView);

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TRAINING,  new String[] { TRAINING_ID,
            TRAINING_TITLE, TRAINING_DESCRIPTION, TRAINING_DATE, TRAINING_LOCATION }, 
            TRAINING_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(TRAINING_ID) }, null, null, null, null);
     Log.d("TAG","cursor found again");


     if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
       cursor.moveToFirst();
       String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
       String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description"));
       String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
       String location = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("location"));
       String allinfos = title+"\n"+description+"\n"+date+"\n"+location;         

       view1.setText(allinfos);
       Log.d("TAG","Successfully set");
     }
    mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long _id) { 
            AlertDialog.Builder b= new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            b.setTitle("Title");

            b.setView(view1);

            b.setPositiveButton("Proceed to training", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TraineeActivity.class));
                }

            });
            b.setNegativeButton("Back to List", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = b.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });

}`
```

Comment: what you want to show in AlertBox on List Item click?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a new textview instead of finding it in your activity layout.
That textView is already added to your layout maybe because of that you are not able to add it to your dialog

Try this:

```
 //Below is the code to alert alert dialogue window on item clicked
    final TextView view1 = new TextView(this);

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TRAINING,  new String[] { TRAINING_ID,
            TRAINING_TITLE, TRAINING_DESCRIPTION, TRAINING_DATE, TRAINING_LOCATION }, 
            TRAINING_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(TRAINING_ID) }, null, null, null, null);
     Log.d("TAG","cursor found again");


     if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
       cursor.moveToFirst();
       String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
       String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description"));
       String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
       String location = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("location"));
       String allinfos = title+"\n"+description+"\n"+date+"\n"+location;         

       view1.setText(allinfos);
       Log.d("TAG","Successfully set");
     }
    mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long _id) { 
            AlertDialog.Builder b= new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            b.setTitle("Title");

            b.setView(view1);

            b.setPositiveButton("Proceed to training", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TraineeActivity.class));
                }

            });
            b.setNegativeButton("Back to List", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = b.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the text **after** the dialog has been created and **after** calling alertDialog.show().